# In React, how do I find the first item in a list that matches some criteria?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm using React 16.13.  How do I find the first item in a list?  Sounds simple, but I tried

```
let value = next(country.id for country in countries if country.code == this.props.countryCode)
```

and it results in the error

```
./src/components/Country.jsx
  Line 9:37:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   7 |                 <option key={country.id} value={country.id}>{country.name}</option>
   8 |             );
>  9 |         let value = next(country.id for country in countries if country.code == this.props.countryCode)  
     |                                     ^
  10 |
```

Here is my component in its entirety.  "countries" is a list of objects that each have a "code" and "id" attribute.

```
class Country extends React.Component {
    render () {
        let countries = this.props.options;
        let optionItems = countries.map((country) =>
                <option key={country.id} value={country.id}>{country.name}</option>
            );
        let value = next(country.id for country in countries if country.code == this.props.countryCode)

        return (
          <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor={this.props.name}> {this.props.title} </label>
            <select
                      id = {this.props.name}
                      name={this.props.name}
                      value={value}
                      onChange={this.props.handleChange}
                      className="form-control">
                      <option value="" disabled>{this.props.placeholder}</option>
                      {optionItems}
            </select>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `next` function is but [array::find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is normally used to find the first element of an array matching a criteria. The error is because it is expecting a comma separated list of function arguments, not several expressions. The entire expression `let value = next(country.id for country in countries if country.code == this.props.countryCode)` is nonsense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to find the id of the first country in the list whose "code" attribute matches a property passed in to the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The error is because it is expecting a comma separated list of function arguments, not several expressions.

## Solution

Use [array::find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search through an array and return the first element matching a criteria/predicate, or `undefined` if no match is found. Since `undefined` can be returned you'll need to check the result first before accessing properties, like `code`.

```
let countries = this.props.options;
let optionItems = countries.map((country) =>
  <option key={country.id} value={country.id}>{country.name}</option>
);

const country = countries.find(country => country.code === this.props.countryCode);
const countryCode = country ? country.code : null;

let value = next(country.id, countryCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const found = countries.find(country => country.code === this.props.countryCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let value = country.filter(con=>(country.code === this.props.countryCode));
```

you can access the value of the desired result country like this

```
value[0].id;
```